# Eco Friendly Alternative to Felt

Tags: sewing, fabric, felt

I have made several toys using acrylic felt and I think the variety and options available in felt is beautiful. Recently I have been more conscious of my impact on the environment and I was wondering if anyone has tried doing "typical felt crafts" (quiet books, toys, fridge magnets etc)  with any other material? The reason I like acrylic felt is mainly due to the vibrant colors and the stiffness of the material. Ecofelt is plastic that has been recycled so I don't want to use that for toys for children and I don't want to use wool either (allergies). Is there any material like cotton (plant based) that can be a replacement for felt? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [cotton felt](https://www.google.com/search?q=cotton%20felt&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), there is [hemp felt](https://www.google.com/search?ei=rNy8WqbzIsaUmwXU0pXQAQ&q=hemp%20felt&oq=hemp%20felt&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i5i30k1j0i8i30k1.28469.31557.0.32891.10.10.0.0.0.0.184.1276.0j8.8.0..3..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.7.1136...0i7i30k1j0i67k1j0i7i10i30k1j0i13k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.YCZTOMDSyt8). Pretty much anything that has fibres (plants including) could be turned into [felt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felt#Manufacturing_methods). If you can't find it in the desired colours you can always dye it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never realized there were plant based options in felt materials. This is great to know.